# Limit folder size by deleting oldest files in OS X

Tags: macos

I run OS X and have a security camera writing images to a folder.

Is there a way to limit this folder's size and then delete the oldest file?

Comment: Yes, you may need to make a script to do it though.  Have you ever programed or written scripts?

Comment: Welcome to super user, for future reference, you should read the help. It is good to list the things that you have tried in your questions.

Comment: Is the camera naming the files in any pattern? The answers given will delete things based on the time they were last modified (because \*nixes like OSX don't store the creation time); the only way to be *really* sure of getting the oldest ones created is if the security camera is embedding the date/time in either the filename or some metadata.

Answer (score 3):

The following shell script deletes the oldest file in the given folder repeatedly until the folder size is below a specified maximum total.

Assumptions:

- You have GNU find installed, e.g. `findutils` from Homebrew
- Doesn't work when files are added faster than the folder size can be determined

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# defensive
set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

# directory to search
DIR=/Users/danielbeck/test

# max folder size in KB
MAXSIZE=1000

# as long as folder size is greater than limit
while [[ $( du -sk "$DIR" | cut -f1 ) -gt $MAXSIZE ]] ; do

    # find the oldest file (modification time counts)
    FILE="$( gfind "$DIR" -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -n | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2- )"

    # delete it
    /bin/rm -v "$FILE"

 done
```

---

You can modify this script a bit to have it run persistently in the background (using e.g. `screen`), or have it launch every minute (or every few minutes) using e.g. `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

Another shell script:

```
cd ~/directory
for f in $(ls -t); do
  sum+=$(stat -f%z "$f")
  ((sum > 10*8)) && rm "$f"
done
```

`10*8` is 100 MB. If the file names contain spaces, add `IFS=$'\n'` before `for`. If the file names can be interpreted as glob patterns, use `set -f` or replace the for loop with something like `while IFS= read -r l; do :; done < <(ls -t)`. Use `-c%s` instead of `-f%z` with GNU stat.

You can run the script every three hours by running `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and adding a line like this:

`0 */3 * * * bash ~/path/to/script.sh`